# How to encode strings in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In previous version of eclipse when I pasted a string btw "" it would encode it automatically like below

```
private String test = "\"ICAgQ0JMIE5VTVBST0MoTUlHKSxGTEFHKEksVyksUkVOVA
```

In the current version(Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)) it does not automatically encode like in previous versions. Do we need to set this somewhere on eclipse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the "escape text when pasting in to a string literal" option in the 'Java > Editor > Typing' page of the Eclipse Preferences.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it was not checked and when I clicked on "restore defaults" "escape text when pasting into a string literal" was checked. Looks like its a default option that was unchecked for some reason.